# Iterating over array of structs with unowned reference goes endlessly

Tags: swift

In my project, I have a struct with an unowned reference to a class instance. Trying to loop through an array of those structs causes my application to loop endlessly. But even crazier, I can loop through an empty array typed to that struct and it still happens.

I used a reference to NSString in this example to make the sample smaller, but using a custom class doesn't help.

Also of note, this behavior only occurs on 64-bit devices and simulators, but not 32-bit ones. I've tested with Xcode 6.1, 6.1.1, and 6.2.

```
struct TestStruct {
    unowned let reference: NSString
}

let anArray: [TestStruct] = []

for anObject in anArray {
    NSLog("This is called endlessly")
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this not a supported arrangement? Or is this just a swift bug that I should report?

Comment: Clearly a bug, wouldn't you say? A really good bug. Nice example, nice testing. Unfortunately I can only upvote once!

Comment: Did you happen to test on your machine and see the issue? I've re-installed Xcode, restarted many times since I discovered this, but I still have a shred of hope that it's somehow my machine.

Comment: Are you nuts? I'm not going to run that code! My computer might explode. You already wrecked yours.

Comment: Ha ha just kidding. Yes, my results agree with yours.

Comment: That makes zero sense. How great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out this appears to be a bug in the Swift compiler. Reporting it via [Apple's Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com) would help us all.

Comment: Mine is rdar://21126703